# Graphical User Interface - Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am doing GUI in tkinter using python 2.7, this is my first time and i can't seem to make the code work - the `COMPARE` button doesn't do anything, it's suppose to display something in `label5`. Also, some processes runs in another file (data loading & processing).

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
import tkMessageBox

class GUI:

    core = None
    root = None

    ctr = 0

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.root = r
        self.root.title("")
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit)
        self.root.minsize(550, 550)

    def set_core(self, c):
        # set the core object
        self.core = c

    def init(self):
        # string assigned to label that gets changed
        self.processing = StringVar()
        self.processing.set(".")

        # create label and assign above processing string, pack it
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.root, textvariable=self.processing)
        self.label.pack()

        self.label2 = Label(self.root, text="", pady = 40)
        self.label2.pack()
        self.label3 = Label(self.root, text="Please enter ", pady = 5)
        self.label3.pack()


        self.pc = StringVar(None)
        self.pCode = Entry(self.root,textvariable = self.pcode, width = 15)
        self.pCode.pack()
        self.key = self.pCode.get()           

        self.button1 = Button(self.root, text='COMPARE', width = 8, pady = 5, command = self.do_compare)
        self.button1.pack()


        self.var5 = StringVar()
        self.label5 = Label(self.root, textvariable=self.var5, pady = 70)
        self.var5.set("Result here...")
        self.label5.pack()

        self.button2 = Button(self.root, text='CLEAR ALL', width = 8, command = self.clear)
        self.button2.pack()

        self.button3 = Button(self.root, text='QUIT', width = 8, command = self.quit)
        self.button3.pack()


        # create button to start the core thread doing work, pack it
        # self.button = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Do work", command=self.do_work)
        # self.button.pack()

        # create another button that can be clicked when doing work, pack it
        # self.button_2 = ttk.Button(self.root, text=str(self.ctr), command=self.inc_ctr)
        # self.button_2.pack()

    def do_compare(self):
        result = ""
        if len(self.key) ==5 or len(self.key) 6:
            result =self.do_work()
            self.var5.set(result)
        else:
            result = 'Invalid Entry, please enter 5-6 alpha numeric characters... !'                        
            self.var5.set(result)

    def quit(self):
        # our quit method to ensure we wait for the core thread to close first
        if not self.core.processing:
            self.core.running = False
            self.root.quit()

    # call back method for button
    def do_work(self):
        self.core.process_request()

    # call back method for clear button
    def clear(self):
        self.var5.set("Result will be here...")
        self.pc.set("")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `do_compare()` method is returning `result`, but that return isn't going anywhere. Just set the Label's textvariable to the variable `result`, and it will update. You also don't need that `bind` method in there, that's not doing anything. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
root = Tk()

def change_var():     # function to get 'result'
    var.set('Result') # set var to 'result'

var = StringVar()                     # create var
var.set('Empty Label')                # set var to value
label = Label(root, textvariable=var) # make label to display var
label.pack()

Button(root, text='Change [var]', command=change_var).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot atlasologist. that bind is really useless.
            'self.var5.set(self.process_request)'

Comment: i did the changes as recommended by atlasologist. However, i do get this error - TypeError: do_compare() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given). Hope someone could enlighten me on this.

Comment: It means that you are passing an extra argument to `do_compare()`. If you want to post a new question or make an edit to this question to include the revised code, it'll help to locate the source of the error.

Comment: i edited the code to include all the changes including the calling of self.core.process_request from core. i don't exactly get where the extra argument comes from, in the do_compare method. Pls help!

Comment: Specifically--how are you *calling* the `do_compare()` method.